# How to parsing the following weather api in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to parse the Weather API (URL) city name, temperature, etc.

My JSON data is the following:

```
{
    "data": {
        "current_condition": [{
            "cloudcover": "25",
            "humidity": "70",
            "observation_time": "04:21 PM",
            "precipMM": "0.3",
            "pressure": "1007",
            "temp_C": "30",
            "temp_F": "86",
            "visibility": "4",
            "weatherCode": "113",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Clear"}],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"}],
            "winddir16Point": "S",
            "winddirDegree": "180",
            "windspeedKmph": "7",
            "windspeedMiles": "4"}],
        "request": [{
            "query": "Ahmedabad, India",
            "type": "City"}],
        "weather": [{
            "date": "2012-09-18",
            "precipMM": "2.1",
            "tempMaxC": "32",
            "tempMaxF": "89",
            "tempMinC": "25",
            "tempMinF": "76",
            "weatherCode": "176",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Patchy rain nearby"}],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png"}],
            "winddir16Point": "SSW",
            "winddirDegree": "203",
            "winddirection": "SSW",
            "windspeedKmph": "12",
            "windspeedMiles": "8"},
        {
            "date": "2012-09-19",
            "precipMM": "3.4",
            "tempMaxC": "32",
            "tempMaxF": "89",
            "tempMinC": "25",
            "tempMinF": "76",
            "weatherCode": "176",
            "weatherDesc": [{
                "value": "Patchy rain nearby"}],
            "weatherIconUrl": [{
                "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png"}],
            "winddir16Point": "SW",
            "winddirDegree": "223",
            "winddirection": "SW",
            "windspeedKmph": "12",
            "windspeedMiles": "7"}]
    }
}​
```

How do I parse this data and get city name and temperature..I have no idea..Thanks in adavance.

===============  OutPut =======================

i want to fetch data like this and Set on Textbox

```
Date        2012-09-18    2012-09-19

tempMaxC    32               32
tempMinC    25               25

tempMaxF    89               89
tempMinF    76               76
```

Comment: What have you tried? Tell us about your idea. Btw: How do you get the JSON, is it already parsed to a JS object?

Comment: You will be able to figure it out if you format that data -> http://jsfiddle.net/88fq6/

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've retrieved this JSON as a string, then pass this string to `JSON.parse()`***** and then access to retrieved value as to a regular JavaScript object:

```
var jsonStr = '{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "25", "humidity": "70", "observation_time": "04:21 PM", "precipMM": "0.3", "pressure": "1007", "temp_C": "30", "temp_F": "86", "visibility": "4", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Clear" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "S", "winddirDegree": "180", "windspeedKmph": "7", "windspeedMiles": "4" } ],  "request": [ {"query": "Ahmedabad, India", "type": "City" } ],  "weather": [ {"date": "2012-09-18", "precipMM": "2.1", "tempMaxC": "32", "tempMaxF": "89", "tempMinC": "25", "tempMinF": "76", "weatherCode": "176",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Patchy rain nearby" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "SSW", "winddirDegree": "203", "winddirection": "SSW", "windspeedKmph": "12", "windspeedMiles": "8" }, {"date": "2012-09-19", "precipMM": "3.4", "tempMaxC": "32", "tempMaxF": "89", "tempMinC": "25", "tempMinF": "76", "weatherCode": "176",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Patchy rain nearby" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0009_light_rain_showers.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "SW", "winddirDegree": "223", "winddirection": "SW", "windspeedKmph": "12", "windspeedMiles": "7" } ] }}',
    jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    console.log(jsonObj.data.current_condition[0].temp_F);
```

Otherwise, if you've retrieved this JSON e.g. as a parameter of some jQuery `$.ajax()` success callback and it's already an object, you don't need to call `JSON.parse()`, but just retrieve object's values directly:

```
$.getJSON("http://example.com/weather.json", function(jsonObj) {
    // The response string is already parsed with $.parseJSON(),
    // so you don't need to parse it yourself.
    // Therefore just go ahead and access the properties of JavaScript object.
    console.log(jsonObj.data.current_condition[0].temp_F);
});
```

***** If you're intended to support older browsers (e.g. IE7) that does not support JSON.parse/stringify, you'll need to include [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

**UPDATE:**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Jv6Gk/) for particular case

Comment: Check my demo (http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/Jv6Gk/) to get an idea.

Comment: hello..one more query please.i am new in jquery & javascript so please help me..i want to pass city name dynamic in below URL ane get json data like table vise...http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=ahmedabad%2cgujarat,india&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=14f868e45b161020121809

Comment: Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/dzcD4/ ?

Comment: hello friend..this code is not run in my apps

Comment: What exactly doesn't run? Can you show some code example which can reproduce the issue?